# Listview must return only the courses that student have puchased in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

My models

User

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
    purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)
```

Course

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    .....
    price = models.FloatField()
```

My Views

```
class StudentPurchasedcourse(ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'tutspack/purchasedcourse.html'
    context_object_name =  'course'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queruset = Course.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.purchased.all()).order_by('title')
        return queruset
```

My Urls.py

```
path('purchased_course/', views.StudentPurchasedcourse.as_view(), name='purchased-course'),
```

I want to return all the courses That student have purchased on the studentViewpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use reverse relation for such query. Start with adding `related_name` to `purchased` field of `User`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True, related_name="buyers")
```

Then you can easily use that name in making queries based on relations:

```
Course.objects.filter(buyers=self.request.user).order_by('title')
```

[More about queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/)